# How to identify clusters of nodes in a network

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, networking, graph

I have a table describing several sets of connected nodes:

```
node
origin_node REFERENCES node
start_time
end_time
```

and I want to find out how many clusters the dataset contains, e.g. if the records were:

```
A, B, 10:00, 11:00
B, C, 9:00, 9:15
D, E, 10:00, 10:15
B, A, 13:00, 13:30
E, B, 12:00, 13:20
F, G, 9:00, 9:15
```

...then I'd have 2 clusters {A,B,C,D,E} and {F,G}

(the times are pretty much irrelevant - it's just there to demonstrate that node+origin_node is not necessarily unique / ordered).

But I'm a bit stuck in working out an algorithm which identifies the clusters from a few thousand rows.

I'm working with MySQL 5.0.22 - so no 'CONNECT BY', and have access to PHP and awk - although it'd be easier for me to understand an algorithm rather than a coded solution. And as long as it takes less than a couple of hours to analyse the data, I'd lean to simplicity over order.

BTW: its a real-world problem - not homework (I stopped being a student a long time ago - perhaps too early ;)

TIA

Comment: before searching for an algorithm, you should formalize well what you're trying to solve, i.e., what are the "formula" that catches your idea of clustering? Are they similar to those used by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this with a single SQL statement in MySQL.  I would approach it more procedurally either as a stored proc or in PHP.  If it is just a few thousand rows, performance shouldn't be a problem no matter how you approach it.  Maybe a HashTable keyed by node with a value of the cluster.  Then you just need to work out merging clusters together.

Comment: @akappa: Perhaps my use of the term clustering is not appropriate since the discussions of clustering algorithms on Wikipedia, although interesting, are based on measuring relative distance of cardinal metrics - while my data is primarily nominal and exists as a a number of sets of overlapping trees (i.e. the resulting composite graphs may contain closed loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with walking the network and flagging visited nodes (similar to garbage collection algorithms). Its reasonably efficient but needed quite a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

> it'd be easier for me to understand an algorithm rather than a coded solution

Tried these links?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Data_clustering_algorithms

Also, though not MySQL, there also is stuff on Microsoft's site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174879.aspx

---

Edit, per your comment:

In your particular case, something akin to creating a closure table might work.

Using a temporary table...

Start with an arbitrary node. Assign it to a new cluster.

Next node. Is there a link to a node from a currently identified cluster?

- If no, assign it to a new cluster.
- If yes, assign it to that cluster. Then, for each link, verify that already processed node is in the same cluster. If not, reassign them to that cluster.

Comment: See my comment in reply to akapa above